# What is causing text values to be empty when posting to db

Tags: php, sql, null

I am appending a form and script that processes an image file upload. I added text fields, a radio button and an additional file-upload.

The image upload and additional file upload portion of the script work fine, as does the radio button. Those values are being saved into my sql db correctly.

However, all the **text fields are submitting empty values into sql.**

Here's the script up to my SQL statement, which remember is working for the URL of the image, document the value of the radio button. But all text fields like 'title' and 'address' are blank in the database.

html form

```
      <div class="avatar-view" title="Change the avatar"> <img src="../0images/cropy.jpg" alt="Avatar"> </div>

      <!-- Cropping modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="avatar-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="avatar-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="avatar-form" method="post" action="crop-avatar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h1>Listing Upload</h1>
                <h2 class="modal-title" style="margin-left:25px;" id="avatar-modal-label">Listing Main Image</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="avatar-body"> 

                  <!-- Upload image and data -->
                  <div class="avatar-upload">
                    <input class="avatar-src" name="avatar_src" type="hidden">
                    <input class="avatar-data" name="avatar_data" type="hidden">
                    <label for="avatarInput">Local upload</label>
                    <input class="avatar-input" id="avatarInput" name="avatar_file" type="file">
                  </div>

                  <!-- Crop and preview -->
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <div class="avatar-wrapper"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="avatar-preview preview-lg"></div>
                      <div class="avatar-preview preview-md"></div>
                      <div class="avatar-preview preview-sm"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="content_add">

                <h2>Listing Data</h2>
<input name="title" type="text" /><br />
<input name="address" type="text"  /><br />
<input name="sale_price" type="text"  /><br />
<input name="lease_price" type="text"  /><br />
<input name="build_size" type="text"  /><br />
<input name="lot_size" type="text"  /><br />
<input name="zoning" type="text"  /><br />
<input name="comment" type="text" /><br />
<input name="transaction" type="text"  /><br />
<h2>Listing Flyer</h2>
                <P class="h4" style="display:inline;">Flyer</P>
                <h6 style="display: inline;">Required</h6>
                <br />
                <input name="flyer" type="file"  />
                <br>
                <br />

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary avatar-save" type="submit">Save and Post Listing</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

php script

```
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $sale_price = $_POST['sale_price'];
        $lease_price = $_POST['lease_price'];
        $build_size = $_POST['build_size'];
        $lot_size = $_POST['lot_size'];
        $zoning = $_POST['zoning'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $transaction = $_POST['transaction'];
            class CropAvatar {
                private $src;
                private $data;
                private $file;
                private $dst;
                private $type;
                private $extension;
                private $srcDir = '../0images/listimg/orig';
                private $dstDir = '../0images/listimg/mod';
                private $msg;

                function __construct($src, $data, $file) {
                    $this -> setSrc($src);
                    $this -> setData($data);
                    $this -> setFile($file);
                    $this -> crop($this -> src, $this -> dst, $this -> data);
                }

                private function setSrc($src) {
                    if (!empty($src)) {
                        $type = exif_imagetype($src);

                        if ($type) {
                            $this -> src = $src;
                            $this -> type = $type;
                            $this -> extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                            $this -> setDst();
                        }
                    }
                }

                private function setData($data) {
                    if (!empty($data)) {
                        $this -> data = json_decode(stripslashes($data));
                    }
                }

                private function setFile($file) {
                    $errorCode = $file['error'];

                    if ($errorCode === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                        $type = exif_imagetype($file['tmp_name']);

                        if ($type) {
                            $dir = $this -> srcDir;

                            if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                                mkdir($dir, 0777);
                            }
        $currdate=date('YmdHis');
                            $extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                            $src = $dir . '/' . $currdate . $extension;

                            if ($type == IMAGETYPE_GIF || $type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG || $type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {

                                if (file_exists($src)) {
                                    unlink($src);
                                }

                                $result = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $src);
        require('../dbcon.php');
        $listing_img="http://www.website.com/0images/listimg/mod/" . $currdate . $extension;
        $allowedExtsf = array("pdf");
        $tempf = explode(".", $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
        $extensionf = end($tempf);

        if (($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
        && ($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] <2000000000)
        && in_array($extensionf, $allowedExtsf)) 
        {
            $flyername=$_FILES["flyer"]["name"];

            if ($_FILES["flyer"]["error"] > 0) 
            {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["flyer"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }   
                else 
                {
                    if (file_exists("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"])) 
                    {
                     echo $_FILES["flyer"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                    }
                        else 
                        {
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["flyer"]["tmp_name"],"../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
                         }
                }
              $ad_link="http://www.website.com/flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"];
                   // escape variables for security

        echo '$title'; echo '$address'; echo '$lot_size'; echo '$ad_link';


        $sql="INSERT INTO listings (listing_img, title, address, lot_size, zoning, build_size, sale_price, lease_price, comment,  ad_link, transaction, date_added) VALUES ('$listing_img', '$title', '$address', '$lot_size', '$zoning', '$build_size', '$sale_price', '$lease_price', '$comment',  '$ad_link', '$transaction', now())";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        mysqli_close($con);
        }
 if ($result) {
                        $this -> src = $src;
                        $this -> type = $type;
                        $this -> extension = $extension;
                        $this -> setDst();


                    } else {
                         $this -> msg = 'Failed to save file';
                    }
                } else {
                    $this -> msg = 'Please upload image with the following types: JPG, PNG, GIF';
                }
            } else {
                $this -> msg = 'Please upload image file';
            }
        } else {
            $this -> msg = $this -> codeToMessage($errorCode);
        }
    }

    private function setDst() {
        $dir = $this -> dstDir;

        if (!file_exists($dir)) {
            mkdir($dir, 0777);
        }

        $this -> dst = $dir . '/' . date('YmdHis') . $this -> extension;
    }

    private function crop($src, $dst, $data) {
        if (!empty($src) && !empty($dst) && !empty($data)) {
            switch ($this -> type) {
                case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                    $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($src);
                    break;

                case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                    $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                    break;

                case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                    $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($src);
                    break;
            }

            if (!$src_img) {
                $this -> msg = "Failed to read the image file";
                return;
            }

            $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor(220, 220);
            $result = imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $data -> x, $data -> y, 220, 220, $data -> width, $data -> height);

            if ($result) {
                switch ($this -> type) {
                    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                        $result = imagegif($dst_img, $dst);
                        break;

                    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                        $result = imagejpeg($dst_img, $dst);
                        break;

                    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                        $result = imagepng($dst_img, $dst);
                        break;
                }

                if (!$result) {
                    $this -> msg = "Failed to save the cropped image file";
                }
            } else {
                $this -> msg = "Failed to crop the image file";
            }


            imagedestroy($src_img);
            imagedestroy($dst_img);
        }
    }

    private function codeToMessage($code) {
        switch ($code) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                $message = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
                break;

            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                $message = 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form';
                break;

            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                $message = 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
                break;

            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                $message = 'No file was uploaded';
                break;

            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                $message = 'Missing a temporary folder';
                break;

            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                $message = 'Failed to write file to disk';
                break;

            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
                $message = 'File upload stopped by extension';
                break;

            default:
                $message = 'Unknown upload error';
        }

        return $message;
    }

    public function getResult() {
        return !empty($this -> data) ? $this -> dst : $this -> src;
    }

    public function getMsg() {
        return $this -> msg;
    }
}

$crop = new CropAvatar($_POST['avatar_src'], $_POST['avatar_data'], $_FILES['avatar_file']);
$response = array(
    'state'  => 200,
    'message' => $crop -> getMsg(),
    'result' => $crop -> getResult()
);

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: try `echo` your sql query and tell the result...

Comment: where? immediately after the query?:

Comment: is your column type in the database varchar?

Comment: print_r($_POST) and check whether you get data correctly in $_POST.

Comment: @arkyc yes, the are mostly varchar

Comment: @Rhillz yes after your query `echo  $sql;`

Comment: I'm running these pages in sessions. and ending each screipt with <?php // Flush the buffered outputob_end_flush();
?> could this be causing my problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're executing the mysql_code inside your CropAvatar class then your variables are out of the class scope. You don't seem to show your entire PHP code (missing some closing tags), therefor I can't be sure.

Comment: I have a feeling this is the problem, still testing. I added the rest of the script, sorry I truncated it initially. I would need all those text fields to enter in the same sql row as the two file URL's. Any suggestions how to pass a id into the CropAvatar class?

Comment: You can store the values in an array and then pass them as a parameter of CropAvatar, or you could make a setter that stores your variables.

Comment: So your right btw, giving you the answer here. I've split it into two sql statements: one outside the class CropAvatar for the text fields, one inside the class CropAvatar for the files. The text fields now work, but the files are null in sql. But the files are still saving to server. I'm still trying to wrap my head around php classes here. You wouldn't happen to have an example of how to pass the array as a parameter would you?  Thank you @Seunhaab for all this by the way.

Comment: You could add the array in the construct method of your class like this: __construct($src, $data, $file, $textInput), and then add the textInput to the new CropAvatar() method.